# Is there a python linter that checks override function return types according to type annotations?

Tags: python, linter

I'm looking for a Python linter, that can check override function return types according to type annotations.
Example:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import List, Dict

class A(ABC):
    """ Some interface """
    @abstractmethod
    def f(self) -> List[str]:
        pass

class B(A):
    """ Interface implementation """
    def f(self):
        return dict()  # Identify this case

class C(A):
    """ Interface implementation """
    def f(self) -> Dict[str, str]:
        return dict()  # Identify this case
```

I've checked flake8, mypy and pylint

---- Edit ----

I intentionally missed the annotation.  Mypy and flake8 can identify when there are function return annotation.
I want to identify the case when I'm defining some interface (class A) and can enforce function type return from inherit classes

Comment: Your question looks exactly the same as example from mypy documentation https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/class_basics.html#overriding-statically-typed-methods

Mypy doesn't yield error in this case cuz function B.f is dynamically typed, so you should use type hints explicitly.

Comment: That exactly what I want to identify. Assuming class A is API and I want to enforce return value type without forcing to annotate the function

Answer (score 0):

you can utilize a type checker such as `mypy`

for example:

```
$ mypy t.py --disallow-untyped-defs
t.py:8: error: Function is missing a return type annotation
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

then adjust the code to fix that error:

```
--- t.py.old    2021-03-07 08:01:43.555176748 -0800
+++ t.py    2021-03-07 08:00:30.376261148 -0800
@@ -5,5 +5,7 @@
         return list()
 
 class B(A):
-    def f(self):
+    def f(self) -> dict:
         return dict()  # Identify this case
```

and then mypy produces an error about incorrect type overrides:

```
$ mypy t.py --disallow-untyped-defs
t.py:8: error: Return type "Dict[Any, Any]" of "f" incompatible with return type "List[str]" in supertype "A"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: I know it can be done, But I need it to enforce the type cheeking by the overrided function (on class A). I can control on class A (some kind of interface) but on class B I don't (I just want to check that the return value is in the correct type)

Comment: @eerez is that not what this does?

Comment: Yes, But I didn't want to force annotations just to check that there is a match between the return value and parent return function annotation. Thanks!

Comment: then I'd say your problem is intractable -- you can't know what type a function will return just from its code in the general case (otherwise there'd be no need for type annotations)